# jQuery toggle not working for image/checkbox on form

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've got a form setup that's using DIVs as the toggles for checkboxes. I've got some jQuery code that watches the DIVs for a click, and then toggles the class to change the image. Easy peasy, right?

I had everything working great, but when I use the checkbox coupled with the product option pricing (as dictated by the plugins for the form & cart I'm using), the jQuery doesn't work.

I assumed that there was another class, or something associated with the pricing construct, overriding the code, but the DIVs look identitcal between the working and non-working version. I'm at a loss as to what's happening—the jQuery should still work based on what I can see.

You can check out the form here: http://bit.ly/YZBdbc

I've got both checkbox examples posted so you can see the difference (under "Choose your options"). The top one works as I'd like visually but doesn't add pricing, the bottom one doesn't toggle, but the pricing works. *Sigh.*

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: Here's the jQuery code:

```
jQuery('#cart_option_1').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
    jQuery('#cart_option_2').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
    jQuery('#cart_option_3').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Here's the DIV code from the working block:

`<div class='ginput_container'><ul class='gfield_checkbox' id='input_1_25'><li class='gchoice_25_1'><input name='input_25.1' type='checkbox'  value='Month-to-Month +$10.00'  id='choice_25_1' tabindex='2'  /><label for='choice_25_1'><div id="cart_option_1b"></div></label></li>`

And the code from the non-working block (which is basically identical):

`<div class='ginput_container'><ul class='gfield_checkbox' id='input_1_26'><li class='gchoice_26_1'><input name='input_26.1' type='checkbox'  value='Month-to-month|10'  id='choice_26_1' tabindex='5'  /><label for='choice_26_1'><div id="cart_option_1"></div></label></li>`

Comment: haha you could always just edit your question...

Comment: Any reason you're repeating `jQuery() ...` instead of `$() ...`?

Comment: It wouldn't work when I just used `$()`. Is that something that would impact the functionality, or just a formatting faux pas?

Comment: its just shorthand, it wouldn't affect anything.

Comment: When I tried to change it from `jQuery()` to `$()` it stopped functioning. Is that normal? (It's probably pretty obvious at this point that I'm not well-versed in jQuery.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it a class.

```
<div class="cart_option" id="cart_option_1"></div>
```

And then apply the click event to the class.

```
$('.cart_option').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Edited for clarification: You can still have the unique images applied to `cart_option_1`, `cart_option_1b`, whatever, but the click event applies to all because they all have the class associated.

Comment: I tried that—you'll notice the first block in the second set has the ID `#cart_option_1b`.

Comment: Ah—I forgot that I changed that after I had copied the code. You looked at what I pasted and made a good observation. That's my bad. I'll change that in my question.

Comment: well take the latter part of my answer. this would be WAY simpler and extensible as a class, not an id, event.

Comment: Unfortunately, they all three have to be unique because they hold unique images.

Comment: you can give the div a unique id to associate the unique img, but make the click event apply to the class. the imgs have nothing to do with the toggleclass methods applied. i modified my answer to show it.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I can watch the process in Firebug, and it does nothing when I click on the one with the `.cart_option` class. When I click on the one that has no class associated (the working one) I can see the class being added.

Comment: Yep. I think there's a jQuery conflict somewhere that has to do with how the price is passed along from the plugin, I just can't find it. I'm sure without that weirdness your solution would have worked. :)

Comment: yeah i mean if you need to use `jQuery` your stuff is borked anyway. without that scope issue resolved, this will not be your last issue by far. i would focus on fixing that first. just my two cents.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Imma mark this as the answer, since the answer is that there is no answer, and all is (essentially) lost on this approach. :)